# What approach should I use for categorizing text with thousands of categories?

Tags: python, text, data-science, categorization

I have a dataset of product descriptions that I need to match with single categories from a very long list (2,265 possible categories).  I'm having trouble figuring out which approach I should use.  I've tried using fuzzy matching using Levenshtein distance/ratio, and that works when the description is fairly similar to the correct category name, but not always.  For example, my first entry is "Gravel and crushed stone", which should be categorized as "All Other Nonmetallic Mineral Mining", but the matching logic isn't catching it.  I have tried to level the playing field by lemmatizing, removing stopwords, sorting the words alphabetically in each entry, and removing duplicate words, but that hasn't had an appreciable effect.

I'm thinking that this might require some kind of supervised or unsupervised learning approach, but I'm not sure where to begin.  Right now I have access only to a dummy data set with 18 rows, but I'm expecting to get access to massive amounts of data in the next few days, and that would give me the option to do train/test splits and train a model properly.  Once that happens, what approach should I use?

Comment: From a computational linguistics perspective, this is a very hard problem. Although there are resources like [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) or [ConceptNet](https://conceptnet.io/) that might help you find some hypnymy relations and such, and there's also vector semantics to get semantic similarity, I don't think a rule-based approach would give you satisfactory results. Best bet IMHO would be to generate a ton of training data (manually in the worst case) and go for a supervised machine learning approach.

Comment: Okay, cool.  That's what I was thinking I should do.  I'll wait for my access to the data to come through, and then try various approaches.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach the problem is by using [glove2word2vec](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/materials/Gensim%20word%20vector%20visualization.html), first on the 100 dimension vector (in case this does not work then go for 300d vector).

For each word you get unique score assigned to it. It also has an API where you can find the most similar word like this:

[image: most similar words around "screw"]

[image: word embeddings]

So find all nouns in your target categories. Get their score. Do not add them, keep them separate.
Eg. Lets say "Gravel"=0.5,"stone"=0.51 and "mining"=0.49 then we see it is closest to "Gravel". [I currently do not have the libraries installed]

To reduce time you can save the scores separately, don't look them up again and again in the 100d/300d corpora, its time consuming.

Edit:
You can try the following for each category:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from itertools import product

description = [w[0].lower() for w in TextBlob("Gravel and crushed stone").tags if w[1].startswith('NN')]
category_1 = [w[0].lower() for w in TextBlob("All Other Nonmetallic Mineral Mining").tags if w[1].startswith('NN')]
max([model.similarity(w[0], w[1]) for w in product(category_1, description)])
```

[image]

Each description is checked across all categories(1 through 2265). Whichever category gives you the highest score, should be the nearest category for that description. You can use DataFrame.apply() to vectorize this and do it much faster. In case you are lucky and all the descriptions are categorized correctly then you only need to do this for, say, first 10K data points. Since now you have the correct labels you can turn to ML instead, then there is no need of this rule based method.

Comment: That looks like it has real possibilities.  I'm trying to work out the Python language now.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you help me out with this a bit more?  I am using the 100d file, and I'm having trouble working out how to bridge the words in the descriptions (i.e., "gravel", "crushed", "stone") with the words in the categories.  Essentially, I want to find the category among the 2,265 available categories that provides me with the best match.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Cool.  I'll work on that today and report back here.  Thanks!

Comment: Not quite yet, though I'm still optimistic that it will.  I'm going to try to take all the words from a category, get their vectors, and find a central point for them, and store that point's vector as a float.  Then I'll do the same thing with the descriptions, and hopefully the descriptions' central point is closest to the central point of the correct category.  Not sure if that will work, but I'm going to keep working on it.

One problem is that some of the categories have exceptions.  For instance, "Citrus (Except Orange) Groves".  I still have to figure out how to deal with that.